# Best resolution for NULL connections?

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-activity

```
my_database_name> SELECT pid, datname, usename, application_name, query_start, state, state_change FROM pg_stat_activity;
+-------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
| pid   | datname          | usename          | application_name         | query_start                   | state   | state_change                  |
|-------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------|
| 19093 | my_database_name | my_user_nam      | pgcli                    | 2020-02-07 12:58:54.665447+00 | active  | 2020-02-07 12:58:54.665449+00 |
| 13777 | my_database_name | some_other_user  | DBeaver 6.3.2 - Main     | <null>                        | <null>  | <null>                        |
| 13776 | my_database_name | some_other_user  | DBeaver 6.3.2 - Metadata | <null>                        | <null>  | <null>                        |
| 2036  | <null>           | <null>           |                          | <null>                        | <null>  | <null>                        |
+-------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Become a member of the `pg_read_all_stats` role, then you can see all data in the view `pg_stat_activity`.